# Comparing two locations to avoid same location to be save in database

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

My app saves user location into Firebase database. I need to compare current location with the location saved in Firebase to avoid same location to be saved in database (if user is at same place).
How can I achieve this?

Here is my code.It doesn't give desired output as it stores same location again n again without comparing.

```
@Override
public void onLocationChanged(final Location location) {

        DatabaseReference dbReference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        Query lastQuery = dbReference.child("User").child("Location").orderByKey().limitToLast(1);
        lastQuery.addListenerForSingleValueEvent(new ValueEventListener() {
@Override
public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
        for(DataSnapshot ds : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {
        lat = ds.child("latitude").getValue(Double.class);
        lng = ds.child("longitude").getValue(Double.class);

        }
   }

@Override
public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {
}
        });

        double latc = location.getLatitude();
        double lonc = location.getLongitude();

        if (distance(lat, lng, latc, lonc) <2.0)
        {
        Log.d("msg","same location");

        }else

        {
        FirebaseDatabase firebaseDatabase = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
        myRef = firebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("User").child("Location");

        DatabaseReference newpost = myRef.push();
        newpost.setValue(latLng);
        }
}

 private double distance(double lat1, double lng1, double lat2, double lng2) {

        double earthRadius = 3958.75; // in miles, change to 6371 for kilometer output

        double dLat = Math.toRadians(lat2-lat1);
        double dLng = Math.toRadians(lng2-lng1);

        double sindLat = Math.sin(dLat / 2);
        double sindLng = Math.sin(dLng / 2);

        double a = Math.pow(sindLat, 2) + Math.pow(sindLng, 2)
                * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat1)) * Math.cos(Math.toRadians(lat2));

        double c = 2 * Math.atan2(Math.sqrt(a), Math.sqrt(1-a));

        double dist = earthRadius * c;

        return dist; // output distance, in MILES
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Store the last "accepted location" object. 
Then check each new Location object and use it's "accuracy" property. 
Simply check it to compare with previous known location. If the accuracy improved and the address is different, then update your accepted location object and store it. If the accuracy is worse or the address is the same, just ditch it.

```
private Location currentLocation;

//inside Location Update Method
if(newLocation.getAccuracy() < currentLocation.getAccuracy()){
    currentLocation = newLocation;
    //update database location info
}
```

Comment: How to compare accuracy?Plz can you give example.

Comment: https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location it has a "getAccuracy()" method that returns how accurate in meters the update is. So simply save ONE local variable of "currentLocation" and each update compare for lower meters in the accuracy. If it's lower, then update, otherwise don't.

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry I'm posting this as answer because I don't have enough reputation points.

The problem resides in that ratio you defined here

```
  if (distance(lat, lng, latc, lonc) <2.0)
```

How you've got that `2.0` ?

Maybe you should `Log` what `distance(lat, lng, latc, lonc)` gives you as a result for a same locations and define according to that your ratio which is in your case here `2.0`.